# Overriden toString() is not called for Object of type Number

Tags: javascript, types, tostring

Why is toString() not called automatically in **console.log("" + x)**? The same situation is for 'alert' function. I read in many places that these functions convert objects to strings with toString() methods of the objects automatically.

```js
Number.prototype.toString = function ()
{
  return "Hello!";
};

x = new Number(42);

console.log("" + x);
console.log("" + x.toString());
```

Before asking the question I was searching for the answer for about two hours. I saw this link [Why does Boolean primitive not call prototype toString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659354/why-does-boolean-primitive-not-call-prototype-tostring/37659580?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). It is something similar but it still does not answer my question. Would be very grateful for a clear explanation.

Comment: Yes, now I understand that the reason here is concatenation. Thank you. Because if I call alert(x) it pops up "Hello". But if I call alert(""+x) it pops up "42".

Answer (score 2):

You could change the [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method and use it for getting a primitive value.

```js
Number.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return "Hello!";
};

var x = new Number(42);

console.log("" + x);
console.log("" + x.toString());
```